# Using global variable in multiple python files

Tags: python

I have a main file and hundreds of sub files which are imported into the main file.Also, i have a global dictionary defined in main.py file.

```
# ../myproject/main.py
import sub1.py
import sub2.py

global dict_test={}

dict_test["fruit"]="apple"
```

How can i get to use this dict_test dictionary in my sub1.py, sub2.py files?

Comment: Why not put the dictionary in a module (say, ``globalvars.py``) and simply import from it?

Comment: I dont want to add any other modules, is there any workaround for using the dict_test in sub1.py ?

Comment: @gokulchand Yes, in main you can call a function from a submodule with the dict as a parameter. In this function, you have then access to this 'global' dict.

Comment: You also don't import files by saying `import filename.py`. You're importing a module named `filename`, so you should just say `import filename`. You'll get an error if you add the `.py` onto it, because Python will look in the `filename` module for a class or function named `py`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it directly, as it will result in a circular input where `main` imports `sub1` and `sub1` imports the dict from `main`.

The way forward is to break the dependency by introducing a third module containing shared resources.

```
`constanst.py`
==============
dict_test = {} 
dict_test["fruit"] = "apple"

main.py
=======
from constants import dict_test

sub1.py
=======
from constants import dict_test
```